# How to use WPF to display localizable and dynamic text?

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF and trying to mash together some concepts I'm reading about.

What I'm trying to do is a build a localizable UI.  For simplicity, let's say I am building a UI with string: "The file takes up 2 GB in disk space."

The "2 GB" portion is dynamic.  The value could change depending upon the file the user selects.  Secondly, a conversion should take from ulong (file size bytes) to string (friendly size, using appropriate units e.g. KB, MB, GB, TB, etc.).

I was thinking an `IValueConverter` would be most appropriate for the byte count to friendly-file-size conversion.  I was also thinking that I'd store "The file takes up {0} in disk space." as a string resource.

I'm not sure the `IValueConverter` will be of use here.  Can it be used with `String.Format()`?  I don't see how it could be used in a binding directly, because we're inserting the conversion result into the localizable text template.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Localization more refers to date and currency formats used by various cultures.  To my knowledge KB, MB, GB, and TB are the same in all cultures.   So I would just use a converter.

Comment: It's obvious that KB, MB, GB, and TB are what he refers to as "dynamic text" and that the "localizable" part is `The file takes up {0} in disk space.` - for i18n/translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings have a [`StringFormat` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx), you should be able to use that if you can somehow reference your localized string (possibly using a custom [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx)).

Comment: Surely this is a standard problem, localizable text templates, isn't it?

Comment: @LemonBeagle: If you look around you might find something here on SO, i for one hate localization and don't want anything to do with it if i can avoid it. If you store the localized strings in your application resources you can reference them using `{x:Static prop:Resources.SomeString}` where prop is mapped to the `Properties` clr-namespace which usually contains those resources. If you use a different mechanism you need to come up with a different method.

Comment: I used this link here: http://www.hardcodet.net/2009/03/lookup-resource-value-using-markup-extension  and it worked beautifully

Comment: @LemonBeagle: As i said a custom markup extension is handy for those things, glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this handy bytes name to text converter and an IValueConverter

[Converting bytes to GB in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242266/converting-bytes-to-gb-in-c)

```
    private string formatBytes(float bytes)
        {
            string[] Suffix = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
            int i;
            double dblSByte=0;
            for (i = 0; (int)(bytes / 1024) > 0; i++, bytes /= 1024)
                dblSByte = bytes / 1024.0;
            return String.Format("{0:0.00} {1}", dblSByte, Suffix[i]);
        }

public class BytesSuffixConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        float bytes = (float)value;
        return formatBytes(bytes);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new Exception("Not Supported.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is more to the problem.  I also want to translate the text to other languages, and dynamically insert this converter's output into that text